# How can I get the language name of the current node?

Tags: 7, nodes, display-suite

I'm trying to figure out how to get the name of the language of the current node in display suite.  I find a language option under one of the node categories in the dynamic field content selector, but that outputs the language code, not the name.  Do I need to handle this in a preprocess function or is there some way of getting this that I've not managed to find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find anything there available for clickers. I could suggest the following alternative:

1. Activate the "Display Suite Format" module
2. Create Display Suite "Code field" with following content:

   ```
   <?php
     return t(locale_language_name($entity->language));
   ?>
   ```
3. Don't forget to activate the "Display Suite code" text format for this code field.
4. Add this code field to your content type's display!

Hope this helps!

Comment: That does look better than what I've done. I got tied up doing something else, but shortly I'll try this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've done.  I'd love a better answer:

in my templates.php in my theme (the dynamic field I created in display suite is called language):

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
    if ($fieldname == 'language') {
        $item['#markup'] = locale_language_name($item['#markup']);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the $GLOBALS['language']; [https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/language/7.x](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/language/7.x) 

`An object containing the information for the active interface language.`

Comment: Yeah, I'm not trying to determine the current interface language.  I'm trying to determine the language of the node.

Comment: Ohh sorry, hmm maybe [menu_get_object] (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7.x)